# Convert bigint data type to timestamp (and subsequently to date) in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I need to convert the value stored in a bigint column to a date field. The first step of the conversion involves converting it to timestamp, and subsequently use the TRUNC method to convert this column to a date value.
However, my query is failing while converting the bigint value to timestamp.
The error that I'm getting is:-

> Amazon Invalid operation: cannot cast type bigint to timestamp without time zone;

The query I'm trying for now is something like this:-

> select ts::timestamp from events limit 1;

Answer (score 3):

I was able to avoid the time zone error by using the method described in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36399361

My dates are based on epochs, and I was able to do the following:

```
SELECT 
  (TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + contract_start_date * INTERVAL '1 Second ')
FROM
  table_name
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
    TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + {column of bigint}/1000 * INTERVAL '1 second' AS adate
FROM tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are starting with a POSIX timestamp, and trying to get a timezone aware datetime value, you will need to supply a timezone - even if you later want to truncate the time part away.  I'm not familiar with redshift, but perhaps there is a way to specify you mean UTC.

Comment: SELECT to_timestamp(1395036000) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'; This happens to be a working postgres query, but it doesn't work in redshift.