# Redshift - Convert epoch string to timestamp

Tags: mysql, amazon-redshift, psql

I have got a table with 2 columns epoch_start and epoch_end.
I want to find the difference in days of these 2 epochs.
The problem i am facing is that the above columns are character varying(5000) type.
The query im running is

> select datediff(day,'1459762341','1450762341') as numdays;

The error i get is

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "1459762341"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found the solution -

1. To get timestamp from epoch -

> SELECT (TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + '1459762341' * INTERVAL '1 Second ') as
>   mytimestamp

2. For datediff between two epochs -

> select datediff(day,(TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + '1458762341' * INTERVAL '1 Second '),            (TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + '1459762341' * INTERVAL '1 Second ')) as numdays;

Answer (score 1):

"epoc" time is just the number of seconds from 1/1/1970, so its just some counter of the number of seconds from that date.

So, epic_start can really be thought of as start_seconds, and epic_end is really just end_seconds.

The fact that they are the count of the number of seconds from the same starting point is the only thing that really matters.

To get the number of days between two numbers representing seconds from the same starting point:

days = (end_seconds - start_seconds)/60/60/24

or

SELECT (end_seconds - epic_start)/60/60/24 AS numdays

Redshift will return an integer value without the decimal portion, so if the formula returns 1.9, numdays will be 1.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing wrong parameters in datediff().

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2014-11-30','2014-11-29') AS DiffDate
```

Above will return the difference in days between two given dates.
Read more on datediff() here [datediff](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

Comment: The data that is available to me is the epoch value as a string.For example - '1459762341'. How do i convert this value to '2014-11-30'.